# Raphael animate based on position not time

Tags: animation, raphael

I have two path elements.  For the sake of description lets just say one is a heart and the other is a square with rounded corners.

I'm trying to get one to interpolate into the other like this:

http://raphaeljs.com/animation.html

This is easy enough to do but I need to do it based off the elements X position and not time.

So as I drag the path element between an Xval of 100 and 200 it will slowly morph into the second path until it finally completes the transformation at an X value of 200.

Does anyone have any idea how I might do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use the drag handler (or you could bind to the mousemove event and feed the coordinates in as well) and use that to move between a starting position and a target animation based on the x or y coordinate and using [Element.status](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.status).  Check out the fiddle (based on yours):

And I'm sorry -- I gave you a copy of your own fiddle back originally.  Terribly poor form =( Try this one instead:

http://jsfiddle.net/kevindivdbyzero/MqFkP/2/

Answer (score 0):

So far this is what I have come up with:

http://jsfiddle.net/jocose/CkL5F/139/

This works but relies on a delay which I am afraid is going to break on slower machines, and plus it seams really hacky.  If anyone knows of a better solution please let me know.